# Cannot align the component in angular web page

Tags: angular

I have an angular page that have multiple components. Simply it is a login form. Refer following image
[image]

As you in the image i need to align user image and password text to left of each text field.

Following is the code

```html
<div>
  <img src="src\assets\images\shutterstock_505757569.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;" alt="" />

</div>
 <div class="transbox">
   <form style="padding-left: 20%; padding-right: 20%">
      <h1 style="font-size:50px">Welcome to Medica</h1>
    <div class="form-field">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="float: left;"> </span>
       <input type="text" style="float: left;"  class="form-control" id="username">
      
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="font-weight: bolder; ">Login</button>
   </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can easily do that with `flex` instead of using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Import bootstrap into your project from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp) and use the predefined bootstrap classes for your help. The update code should be like

```
    <div class="form-field col-sm-12">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user col-sm-4" style="float: left;"> </span>
       <input type="text" style="float: left;"  class="form-control col-sm-8" id="username">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
      <label class="col-sm-4" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control col-sm-8" id="pwd">
    </div>
```